# Debian KDE WIFI not working

Tags: debian, wifi, kde

So I've recently switched from Manjaro to Debian and I've been working with it on my desktop pc for a while now. Now I decided to change my laptop from Manjaro to Debian as well however there seems to be some kind of issue with the WIFI.

I've read through a few sources and tried everything from making sure there is only one networkmanager installeld, changing NetworkManager.conf manged to true.

Latop: XPS 15 7590

`lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3`:

```
3b:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:2723] (rev 1a)
Subsystem: Bigfoot Networks, Inc. Device [1a56:1654]
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [linux-hardware](https://linux-hardware.org/index.php?id=pci:8086-2723-8086-0080) the the new wifi card should work under linux kernel `5.7` and newer. It can be achieved by installing the [kernel from buster-backports](https://packages.debian.org/buster-backports/linux-image-amd64).

```
printf "%s\n" "deb http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-backports main" |\
sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/buster-backports.list
sudo apt update
sudo apt install -t buster-backports linux-image-amd64
```

Download the [Intel® Wi-Fi 6 AX200 160MHz](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005511/network-and-i-o/wireless.html) and follow the install instructions:

```
wget https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/_media/en/users/drivers/iwlwifi/iwlwifi-cc-46.3cfab8da.0.tgz
tar xvf iwlwifi-cc-46.3cfab8da.0.tgz
cp iwlwifi-cc-46.3cfab8da.0/* /lib/firmware
```

Then reboot and disable the secure boot.

```
sudo reboot
```